# Why do I have an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getTracks')", but the code is working?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code :

```js
            const videoElem = document.getElementById("videoScan");
            var stream = document.getElementById("videoScan").srcObject;
            var tracks = stream.getTracks();
            tracks.forEach(function (track) {
                track.stop();
            });
            videoElem.srcObject = null;
```

I am trying to stop all camera streams in order to make ZXing work. However, I have the following error (**only on android tablet**) :

[image]

Problem is, I can't solve it, but everything is working well. And when I do a try/catch, code stops working. I can't figure out why this error is displaying.

Comment: `await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules` This is the actual error.

Comment: No the code is *not*  working. It is throwing an exception because `stream` is `null` ...

Comment: @aca I edited the code and error of the question with the code without "await" statements

Comment: @derpirscher, but how is it explainable that it works without try/catch and not with ?

Comment: depends on what you mean by "work". It doesn't print an error in the console with `try .. catch` because you are probably just ignoring the error in the catch clause. But the last three lines of code won't be executed in any case if `stream` is null. And it's null, because that's what the error is telling you

Comment: Like I said in comments, it is a mistake from me to say that this is working. I meant that the expected outuput is working, not the code. I noticed that the fucntion of cutting streams happens multiple times. This is why it is null. But it is not the 1st time.

Comment: Sounds like your code is ran twice. Add a log in there to see when it's called. If you can't find it, then you can try `video.addEventListener("emptied");` to see if it's fired before your code runs.

Comment: @Kaiido yes absolutely, I've made a mistake. Debug helped me to understand why, next time, I'll put more of my code in the question because it was not enough in this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "*everything is working well*", you mean that you get what you want as output?

If the code throwing the error is the same you are showing us, then it means that `streams` contains `null`.

Since `streams` is a `const` value (thus once only) assigned on the previous instructions, it means that `document.getElementById("videoScan").srcObject` is null too.

I'd suggest you to do some other debug by, i.e., printing out to JS console (if you have access to it from your Android debug environment, I'm sure there's a way) what's inside `stream`, before trying to access its `getTracks` method reference.

Please do also check the compatibility with `srcObject` with your Android (browser?) environment: MDN has a [compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject#browser_compatibility) you can inspect.

Comment: Yes, it is a mistake from me. The expected output is working, not the code. I tried to print each variable in console. And indeed, stream is null. But it is null when it triggers the second time.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to catch this null reference error, is to check if `tracks` actually exists.

```
const videoElem = document.getElementById("videoScan");
const stream = videoElem.srcObject;

if (stream && stream?.getTracks()) {
  const tracks = stream.getTracks();
  tracks.forEach(function (track) {
    track.stop();
  });
} else {
  console.warn('Stream object is not available');
}

videoElem.srcObject = null;
```

Comment: I've tried that, there is no more error about "stream", but now, expected output is not working and I have the following error with ZXing : *Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source*. And, from my searches, it is due to the camera not stopped on Android, which block any other camera to trigger. This is why I try to cut all streams to allow opposite camera to start.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution. The error stopped the code from continuing, which, in my case, actually made it work. I made a very basic mistake : not paying enough attention to the debug results. However, if anyone has the error "***Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source***" with ZXing on Android, you simply have to cut all video streams to allow chrome starting an other camera. It will not work otherwise.